# Limitations on privileges based on experties

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I have noticed some abuse of some features like edit/downvote on some places by inexperienced people who are irrelevant to the target subject.
For example, someone asks about C++ code and another guy who does not have C++ in his skills comes and downvotes without an explanation.
I do understand that on Meta the downvote can be done just for disagreeing with someone. However, it is not the same on StackOverflow.
I actually had a similar incident. I asked a question about an algorithm and its understanding and I got some downvotes and one comment. That comment poster did not have a clue about the algorithm nor how it works and yet he was able to mark the question as bad which lead others not to answer the question later on.

My suggestion: 
It would be better if users with no experience in the asked question cannot downvote nor edit the question while they keep their right to answer/comment.

I would like to hear your comments and why would this be a good idea or why it would be a bad idea. 
Thanks.

Edit: Is it reasonable that a question gets down-voted 10 seconds after it is posted? Before even anyone could read it?

Comment: well, on this site you can become an expert about **discussions** and even get the power to single handed close any "discussion" that may pop up, so....  Anyway, more seriously - I will give to you my usual suggestion : remove any indication in the post that may give the idea (or the excuse) that you post is a rant about some downvotes that you got and your post *may* be regarded with more attention. (continues)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you basically are arguing that on very "generic" sites the privileges got from rep like closure powers or flagging are given without any regard to the actual "expertise areas": that is something many other users actually noticed too, and I think some questions in that regards were already made in the past. Sadly, I can't think of a way that could "scope" privileges without fracturing sites like Stack Overflow to the point of becoming unusable, so you may need to try to devise a solution to propose first. Try that, and I would love to consider it and maybe support it too

Comment: "Is it reasonable that a question gets down-voted 10 seconds after it is posted? Before even anyone could read it?" - I am a speed reader.  I can read a question like this, in a couple seconds, what you describe isn't abuse of the voting system.

Answer (score 12):

> another guy who does not have C++ in his skills comes and downvotes without an explanation

Uhm, you should have a crystal ball or something... How do you know who downvoted? In particular if no one commented, how do you know that user is inexperienced in a tag?

Every user is free to use their votes as they think is necessary (with some restrictions on serial voting). I am not experienced in C++, but I can spot a tool recommendation question, or spam. So why shouldn't I be able to vote (downvote or vote to close) or flag? That doesn't make sense.

Generally, if a question gets closed for wrong reasons, the community will correct that. If not, ask on the site's meta if the question should be reopened and why people think it should be closed. Most of the time your question is kept closed, since the users closing it have quite some experience what is allowed on a site and what not.

Comment: When you see a question with bad content you would comment explaining why you think it is bad. Down-votes could really destroy the asker's chance of getting an answer even if the down-voters did not have a clue about the question. I said in the post that I have had a similar incident. Please respond to that.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. Maybe the question was too broad. Maybe it wasn't researched very well. Most of the time I downvote, I also vote to close, so that will lead up in a notification. Generally I would also comment why I think it is a bad question. Users are not required to do so though.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. But my problem was with the guy who commented. He really did not know a bit about the algorithm I was asking about. No clue. He literally did not know how it works and yet he cut-off my chances of getting an answer. Even until now I still haven't found the answer because people would just see down-votes and ignore the whole question.

Comment: Usually one single downvote is easily corrected by the community. Also, a single downvote doesn't immediately destroy your chances for an answer. Maybe the question is just too hard to answer? Again, you are making assumptions about what people think and do.

Comment: In the matter of fact, it takes at least 2 minutes to read the question and the down-vote came 10 seconds after it was posted. I mean, if someone does not bother to read the question why down-voting? Even without having an idea about the subject involved? I ended up deleting the question because I am new and that decreases reputation effectively.

Comment: Maybe they already disagreed on the title only.

Comment: I do know people's phycology. Usually when people see something with up-votes they tend to up-vote even if they disagree. Same thing happens the other way around. I've seen that happen a lot. All I am saying is that careless guys should be handled in a better way. After all, people are here for answers not for bad comments

Comment: I'm pretty much 100% sure the title was involved in the subject. When you have an algorithm and you want to test a special case what would you title your question?

Comment: I thought you were referring to this question @AmmarSalman

Comment: I was referring to the question that I yet do not know the answer and it was really frustrating how some carelessness from someone would do such stuff.

Comment: Can you link the question?

Comment: As I have mentioned I deleted it. It is not easy for new users to handle down-votes as older ones.

Comment: I can see deleted question. Please give a link and I will try to help you.

Comment: "But my problem was with the guy who commented. " - You also claim this same person, voted your question as being unhelpful except voting is anonymous, so you actually have no idea if he did so or not.  You also instead of improving the question decided to just delete the question.  Your question wasn't all that spectacular by the way.

Answer (score 9):

> another guy who does not have C++ in his skills comes and downvotes
>   without an explanation.

You shouldn't assume that, because you can't know it. Votes are anonymous.

> I asked a question about an algorithm and its understanding and I got
>   some downvotes and one comment. That comment poster did not have a
>   clue about the algorithm nor how it works and yet he was able to mark
>   the question as bad which lead others not to answer the question later
>   on.

Maybe the commenter didn't downvote? You still can't know that. Maybe a guy with 10+ years C++ experience downvoted you?

Your suggestion is based on an erroneous assumption. You don't know who downvoted. Every user is free to use their votes as they please, as long as they're not serially targeting any one user. This is one of the central points of this site.

Comment: So by assuming the opposite you deny the original? Your assumption is equally likely as my assumption in the current way. And my suggestion is to make what I assumed less likely to happen, and so your assumption will have an advantage.

Comment: Right. But you want a change, so the burden of convincing the rest of us is on you. I'm outlining that you can't demand change based on conclusions you drew from making (likely incorrect) assumptions.

Comment: I was suggesting something and came here to see why and why not would my suggestion be reasonable. And I really am not convinced so far by the opposite. I am pretty much sure if I had +50k reputation then my same suggestion would've been treated elsewise.

Comment: Why (likely incorrect)? And why are your assumptions (likely correct)? Both you and I know that both of our assumptions are equally probable. And I am pretty much sure the guy who commented down-voted because his comment was negative towards the question.

Comment: _"Both you and I know that both of our assumptions are equally probable"_ Thats not true. Generally, people who care about and know about technologies are more likely to read and by extension vote on questions about them on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -3):

Blind up/downvotes are such a big issue on any Stack Exchange site. As others mentioned, we don't know whether they were cast by an expert or non-expert. Based on your profile, you seem to be very new to Stack Exchange, just three questions asked, two on SO and one here.

Adding to other two great answers, your suggestion doesn't work because there is no way to evaluate each user' expertise and knowledge. For example, I am not a computer guy and I don't know a thing about software and computer language. But as long as I can manage to get 24 reputation points, for example, 12 successful edits on Stack Overflow, I can downvote any question I want.

I think the problem lies there. The privilege to downvote is set at the level which is too low and not that difficult to achieve. Increasing the rep points for downvote privilege will not solve the problem entirely, but I think it could help alleviate the issue you raised.

There are some upvotes that are cast by non-experts without knowing the contents. You will receive some of them in the future which will hopefully offset the problem you raised.

When your post gets downvoted, it is always better to check whether it has some mistakes, wrong information, or it is poorly-researched. There are many more reasons why other users downvote your post.

Comment: What about me then? I have comfortable 4800 reputation on stack overflow. That still doesn't mean I have any idea about say PHP or Ruby.

Comment: @Magisch Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I said 24 rep points for users with an association bonus are too low.

Comment: I mean by that that higher rep doesn't preclude people from being uninformed on any particular subject. I'm sure there 50k users on SO who don't even have the faintest hint of a clue about C++. So restricting downvoting to more rep won't do much. Also, as a tendency, the higher a user's rep gets, the more they tend to downvote vs upvote. Low rep users tend to upvote more.

Comment: @Magisch You are assuming that my suggestion would not work that well, I am assuming otherwise. We seem to have some difference here. I don't agree low rep users tend to upvote more, especially on each site's meta when they don't lose a point when downvoting. Also, I think *low rep users' upvoting* is causing more problem than downvoting.

Comment: _Also, I think low rep users' upvoting is causing more problem than downvoting_ Thats an entirely different discussion then, and one I may be more inclined to agree with. This thread though is about downvoting.

Comment: Well, SE sets the bar at 2,000 for edit, 3,000 for close-vote, 10,000 for delete-vote. Why does it set at 0 for upvote and 24 for downvote which plays a very important role in showing which question (or answer) is well-researched and useful. If you don't agree with me saying 24 rep points are too low, that's fine. But just because you have 4,800 points and don't know much about PHP or Ruby doesn't mean my suggestion doesn't work. That was also different discussion.

Comment: @Rathony - Does not take a Ruby or PHP expert to tell if a question is clear.  We all use the same language to ask the question.

Comment: "Blind up/downvotes are such a big issue on any Stack Exchange site." - In this case, a comment accompanied the downvote, explaining the problem with the question. The asker then denigrated the commenter, saying they were providing "false content". The problem here wasn't the ease of downvoting, it was someone taking downvotes personally instead of listening to the constructive criticism provided. On Stack Overflow, people cast 6.8 upvotes for each downvote in [the last 90 days](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179710/voting-ratio-last-90-days).

Comment: @BradLarson Well, I am not arguing the vote was cast blindly. I am trying to explain it could have been one of many possible factors. I don't know how SO works as I mentioned in the answer, but I am very sure that blind upvotes and downvotes are problems in other sites. Also, I doubt they don't exist on SO.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I don't know a thing about Ruby or PHP. Maybe I am not using the same language, then.

Comment: @Rathony - I was trying to indicate, we both communicate using the English language, if a question is not clear that is a communication problem which should be resolved.  Some questions are just not good questions (for many reasons outlined in the help center), in that case, you can't improve them.  *I don't need to know PHP or Ruby to answer a question that asks a clear question.*  "I don't know how SO works " - It is a Q&A website, you ask a question, you receive an answer.  Helpful questions gets positive votes, unhelpful questions, receive negative votes.

Comment: @Ramhound I have more than one year experience on SE. I know how it works where I am active. You missed one very important part. There are other sites where you can't tell if questions are helpful or unhelpful, Korean, Japanese, other language sites. There are many who vote who don't know shit about the language. BTW, how do you know if a question is clear or not if you don't know PHP or Ruby? I wouldn't. I think it would be more difficult for me to tell than Korean or Japanese SE because I speak Korean and Japanese fluently.

Comment: Outside of the specific language sites, which are the exception, not the norm SE questions are written in English

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know who you are, nor can I understand why you are using this user name here. I will stop here if you mean as long as any question on any subject is written in English, you are the expert.